# Why is my question opinion based

Tags: support, closed-questions

My question [Why is the Breeze theme a flatpak?](https://askubuntu.com/q/1408798/1165986) is closed for being opinion based. If you ask why a certain package is a flatpak instead of a normal `.deb` package, it is not opinion based. It is just a question. The fact that I want as few flatpaks and snaps on my system *is* opinion, but that has nothing to do with the question. Therefore I think that closing the question for being opinion-based was and still is not the right thing to do.

Comment: I see your question reopened, so a good result there. Meta is perfectly fine for such questions but keep in the back of your mind you also have access to at least 2 Chat rooms where assistance and support can also be provided in such matters (as well as some general chat!): 1. https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/3877/raiders-of-the-lost-downboat 2. https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/201/ask-ubuntu-general-room.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> ... it is not opinion based. It is just a question.

It's possible that you may be confused slightly on the close reason, but that's entirely understandable.  The banner at the top clearly (and yet confusingly!) says:

> This question is [opinion-based](https://askubuntu.com/help/closed-questions).

However, the problem isn't that the *question* is based on opinion.  If you follow the help page that's linked, the problem is that:

> This question is likely to be answered with opinions rather than facts and citations. It should be updated so it will lead to fact-based answers.

So it's not your question, it's that the *answers* to it are likely to be opinion-based.

> Why is it a flatpak?

This, in itself, seems to be your main (at least first) question; and many people would consider the reason *why* to be a matter of opinion.  Unless the author of the theme answers, the rest of us can probably only speculate on why it was packaged as a Flatpak rather than a `.deb`.  My guess/opinion, for instance, would be that the theme's author felt it was easier to target multiple distributions with a Flatpak than to limit themselves to Debian-based distributions or have to create multiple packages.

From there, it's entirely too possible to get into a "war of competing opinions" in the "answers" as to whether or not things like this *should* be packaged as Flatpaks, etc.  That's the type of "forum"/"discussion" behavior that Stack tries to avoid so that it remains focused on being a "Question and Answer" site.

But given the *rest* of your context, and the answer that you accepted, it seems your "real question" is more around:

- Why did this Flatpak get installed on my system?
- Is it safe to remove this Flatpak?
- Is there a similar theme available via the standard repositories?

Personally, as a voter, I probably would have take the full context of the question into account and left a comment recommending that you rewrite or replace the, "Why is it a flatpak" portion.

But I can certainly see how readers/voters zero'd in on that particular question, especially since it is the first listed.

It's *likely* (IMHO) a very easy reopen with some minor changes.
Consider editing to replace, "Why is it a flatpak?" with something like:

- Why did this get installed on my system as a Flatpak? (which I see @Dan has done in an edit just now)
- Is there a technical reason why this needs to be a Flatpak?

However, note that I might be missing part of the reason why people voted to close as Opinion-based, so I'd encourage you to look for other comments/answers/suggestions here as well.